# How to make an SCNNode facing toward ARAnchor

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

How can I make an `ARNode` pointing to an `ARAnchor`?

I want to use `art.scnassets/ship.scn` showing in the center of the screen and pointing to the object I just placed somewhere in the scene.

```
/// ViewController Class
func placeObject() {
    let screenCentre : CGPoint = CGPoint(x: self.sceneView.bounds.midX, y: self.sceneView.bounds.midY)
    guard let hitTestResult = sceneView.hitTest(screenCentre, types: [.featurePoint]).first else { return }

    // Place an anchor for a virtual character.
    let anchor = ARAnchor(name: identifierString, transform: hitTestResult.worldTransform)
    sceneView.session.add(anchor: anchor)
    // add to item model
    ItemModel.shared.anchors.append((identifierString, anchor)

}

func showDirection(of object: ARAnchor) { // object: saved anchor

    if !Guide.shared.isExist {
        let startPoint = SCNVector3(0, 0 , -1)
        let targetPoint = SCNVector3(object.transform.columns.3.x, object.transform.columns.3.y, object.transform.columns.3.z)

        let guideNode = Guide.shared.setPosition(from: startPoint, to: targetPoint)

        // add the ship in the center of the view
        sceneView.pointOfView?.addChildNode(guideNode)

    }
}
/// Guide Class   
func setPosition(from start: SCNVector3, to target: SCNVector3) -> SCNNode {
    isExist = true
    guideNode.position = start
    targetPosition = target

    // create target node from saved anchor
    let desNode = SCNNode()
    desNode.position = targetPosition

    let lookAtConstraints = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: desNode)
    guideNode.constraints = [lookAtConstraints]

    return guideNode
}

// MARK: - ARSCNViewDelegate
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    if let name = anchor.name, name.hasPrefix(identifierString) {
        // Create 3D Text
        let textNode: SCNNode = createNewBubbleParentNode(identifierString)
        node.addChildNode(textNode)
    }

}
```

I tried `SCNLookAtConstraint` but it does not work as expected, any suggestions?

[image: demo]

Comment: I noticed that it works ONLY when the orientation of the phone is horizontal.

Comment: As I see it everything is fine except back side is pointing towards 'banana'. reason is in `SCNLookAtConstraint` the part facing backwards (-z axis) will act as pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed that the `SCNLookAtConstraint` works when the orientation of my phone is parallel to the horizon. (screen facing upward)

And this line of code does the magic !! `guideNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4Rotate(guideNode.pivot, Float.pi, 0, 1, 1)`

If you're interested, see [here](https://github.com/Willjay90/Gotcha).

```
 public func showDirection(of object: arItemList) {

    guard let pointOfView = sceneView.pointOfView else { return }

    // remove previous instruction
    for node in pointOfView.childNodes {
        node.removeFromParentNode()
    }

    // target
    let desNode = SCNNode()
    let targetPoint = SCNVector3.positionFromTransform(object.1.transform)
    desNode.worldPosition = targetPoint

    // guide
    let startPoint = SCNVector3(0, 0 , -1.0)
    let guideNode = loadObject()
    guideNode.scale = SCNVector3(0.7, 0.7, 0.7)
    guideNode.position = startPoint

    let lookAtConstraints = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: desNode)
    lookAtConstraints.isGimbalLockEnabled = true
    // Here's the magic
    guideNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4Rotate(guideNode.pivot, Float.pi, 0, 1, 1)

    guideNode.constraints = [lookAtConstraints]
    pointOfView.addChildNode(guideNode)
}
```

Comment: Hey did you see this  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/2867394-lookat?language=objc

Answer (score 3):

I don't know this will help you in your case or not. (If not i will delete my answer)

So I have faced same issue. Where I am drawing wall between two SCNVector object. Issue is wall is double sided so in some case part visible to camera is flipped.

like If you draw wall from two vectors and then add another Node (Plane Node) with same Euler Angle added Node (Plane) is Vertically Flipped.

I have searched many solution and tried many things but this working for me.

```
class func node(from:SCNVector3,
                to:SCNVector3,height:Float,needToAlignToCamera:Bool) -> SCNNode {
    let distance = MathHelper().getMeasurementBetween(vector1: from, and: to)

    let wall = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(distance),
                        height: CGFloat(height))
    wall.firstMaterial = wallMaterial()
    let node = SCNNode(geometry: wall)

    // always render before the beachballs
    node.renderingOrder = -10


    // HERE IS MAGIC LINES 
    //============================================

    let normalizedTO = to.normalized()
    let normalizedFrom = from.normalized()
    let angleBetweenTwoVectors = normalizedTO.cross(normalizedFrom)

    var from = from
    var to = to

    if angleBetweenTwoVectors.y > 0 && needToAlignToCamera {
        let temp = from
        from = to
        to = temp
    }
    //============================================


    node.position = SCNVector3(from.x + (to.x - from.x) * 0.5,
                               from.y + height * 0.5,
                               from.z + (to.z - from.z) * 0.5)

    // orientation of the wall is fairly simple. we only need to orient it around the y axis,
    // and the angle is calculated with 2d math.. now this calculation does not factor in the position of the
    // camera, and so if you move the cursor right relative to the starting position the
    // wall will be oriented away from the camera (in this app the wall material is set as double sided so you will not notice)
    // - obviously if you want to render something on the walls, this issue will need to be resolved.


    node.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(0, -atan2(to.x - node.position.x, from.z - node.position.z) - Float.pi * 0.5, 0)


    return node
}
```

Extension

```
func cross(_ vec: SCNVector3) -> SCNVector3 {
        return SCNVector3(self.y * vec.z - self.z * vec.y, self.z * vec.x - self.x * vec.z, self.x * vec.y - self.y * vec.x)
    }

func normalized() -> SCNVector3 {
        if self.length() == 0 {
            return self
        }

        return self / self.length()
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`ARKit` updates positions of anchors and corresponding nodes provided via delegate method `renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode?`

So your constraints idea is correct, but you need to provide nodes via the delegate method instead of adding them directly to the scene.

Something like that -

```
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
        switch anchor {
        case MyAnchor:
          let constraint = // ...
          let node = // ...
          node.constraints = [constraint]
          return node
        default:
          return nil
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more? I've updated my code, and it's not working either.

Comment: I think both `showDirection` and `setPosition` methods are wrong. You need to provide `guideNode` in delegate method and set constraints in the same method.

Comment: I just fixed the `ship` at the center of the screen with `sceneView.pointOfView.addChildNode`, and I want the `ship`(node) point to the `anchor` (another node). The delegate method is not always called, so how can I set the constraints?

Comment: That's the problem. Add subclassed *anchors* to the *session* for every object, for example GuideNodeAnchor. Do *not* add any *nodes* to the *scene* directly, only provide them via *delegate* method.  If you set constraint in that delegate method, ARKit will take care that it is always enforced.